# Search Engine Visibility Issue in WordPress

Tags: search

There is an issue in the back-end that the Search Engine Visibility Checkbox is  disabled and I'm not able to check or uncheck the checkbox.

What is happening that when I load the page then it comes normal but at the end of loading it will appear like in below image.

I have uninstalled my all plugins and renamed the plugin directory too, but this issue still persist.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [plego.us](http://email.plego.us/3dp/search-engine-visibility.jpg))</sub>

robots.txt Code.

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 1
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

Any help will be appreciating.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want your **staging** site be found by search engines? Also, this looks very much as if there is a mu-plugin in place. Some web hosts are doing that, WPEngine for example.

Comment: Actually I don't know why staging site is coming. Because I am on live site.

Comment: If you didn't set it up that way, your web host did. Ask them, you are paying for support after all.